# Performance measure: EventCount VS condition_variable

Tags: c++, multithreading

[EventCount](https://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/eventcounts) is an implementation of lock-free condition variable. I am wondering if there have some methods to measure its performance with normal condition_variable implemented in cpp standard.

Personally, I think EventCount only increase the performance in the fast path. Since it still fall into system-call in the worst case.

Here are some implementations of EventCount in famous open-source libraries:

- [folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/main/folly/experimental/EventCount.h)
- [Eigen](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/ThreadPool/EventCount.h)

Comment: ```std::atomic<T>::wait``` in C++20 would achieve something similar. And yes, it's only useful in the fast-path but that's also what you care about the most

Comment: Can we have some theoretical analyzations or experiments to prove the benefits?